# Definite integrals in terms of $W_0,W_{-1}$, which have the opposite signs

Tags: definite-integrals, lambert-w

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

Consider definite integral
\begin{align} 
I_n&=
\int_0^1
\frac{\W_{n}(-t/\e)\ln(-\W_{n}(-t/\e))^2}
{t\,(1+\W_{n}(-t/\e)^2)(1+\W_{n}(-t/\e))}
\, dt
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

where $n=0,-1$ and $\Wp,\Wm$ are the two real branches of
the Lambert W function (also known as ProductLog).

Surprisingly, for $n=-1,0$

\begin{align}
(-1)^{n+1}I_n=
I_{-1}=-I_{0}
&=
\frac{\pi^3}{16}
\approx 1.9378922925
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Question: Are there any other known definite integrals
in terms of $\Wp,\Wm$ with the same property?

Somewhat related is
[Integrals invariant to the choice of the real branch of the Lambert W...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3521827/122782),
but there the sign is the same.

$\endgroup$

Comment: shouldnt it be: $I_0=-\frac{1}{e}\frac{\pi^3}{16}$?

Comment: @Henry Lee:
No, $I_0=-\frac{\pi^3}{16}\approx -1.93789$,
see [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28W%28-t%2Fe%29*ln%28-W%28-t%2Fe%29%29%5E2%2F%28t*%281%2BW%28-t%2Fe%29%5E2%29*%281%2BW%28-t%2Fe%29%29%29%2Ct%3D0..1%29)

Comment: does this integral not just simplify to $$-\frac{1}{e}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(x)}{x^2+1}dx$$ though

Comment: @Henry Lee: it does, but without the factor $1/e$.

Comment: ah i must have missed something during substitution then